# getting text form locally stored html files with python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, code-formatting

I have some locally stored .html files and I am trying to read the text in, which I use for further data preprocessing. However, my program is always displaying the html code in the beginning as well and not just the plain text. It's just at the beginning, the rest of the document looks good (just plain text and no html code)

I already tried different methods (with urllib, beautifulsoup or codecs) but haven't really been successful and I do not know where I should look for the problem. My code looks like the following:

```
original = open("path/1.html", "r")
original_text = original.read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(original_text)
f_out = open("path/1.ann", "w")
```

when opening the .ann files, this is what I see at the beginning. After this, just plain text is displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html id="a2gEWnT1MVFW6UkGVvB8Yxeiawb0-27" data-origid="27" class="anndoc" data-anndoc-version="3.6" lang="" xml:lang="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="generator" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article>
      <section data-type="">
        <div class="content">
          <p id="s1p1">&quot;
normal text being displayed here
```

Does someone might have a clue why the program isn't able to correctly parse the text from the .html file or what do I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the excepted output ?

Comment: the plain text of the .html file

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup provides an object which you can navigate or iterate through in order to find the text you desire. Have a look at their documentation here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Particularly, to get all the text in the document, you want to do `bs.get_text()` and write that to a file (if that is a requirement).

```
# Good practice to use open() as a context manager to automatically close
# the file after reading
with open("path/1.html", "rt") as html_file:
    original_text = html_file.read()

bs = BeautifulSoup(original_text)

with open("path/1.ann", "wt") as ann_file:
    ann_file.write(bs.get_text())
```